# Httpcomponents-client proxy problems

Tags: proxy, apache-httpcomponents

I have problems when trying to connect to the internet via a proxy using the new httocomponent-client module

If I use directly the Proxy object and HttpURLConnection everything goes fine:

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("somehost", 8080));
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(proxy);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

Now I try to do the same with the new api:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("somehost", 8080, "http");
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("http://www.google.com");
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("/");
try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpGet);
    System.out.println(httpResponse.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ) [Via: 1.1 xxx, Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate, Proxy-Authenticate: Kerberos, Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM, Connection: Keep-Alive, Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive, Pragma: no-cache, Cache-Control: no-cache, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: 7079  ]
```

I also tried

```
ProxySelectorRoutePlanner routePlanner = new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(
httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(),new MyProxySelector());  
    httpClient.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
```

Where MyProxySelector return the Proxy that I nned but no result.

Why using the new API makes the proxy authentication required inside the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the solution with ProxySelectorRoutePlanner doesn't work, are you sure you start your JVM with the proxy settings ?

It looks like you need to add this line :

```
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("yourProxyHost", Port),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("yourUsername", "yourPass"));
```